# No form of window into EXE

Tags: python, printing, exe

So I'm making a python game with no form of a window popping up, only commands like

```
print("Welcome to Game!!!")    
name = input("Whats your name???")    
print("Hello, " + name)
```

and such. and I wonder, if I turn this into a home, well it open a terminal or shell or something, so I'm asking anyone who has done this before and if I'm wasting my time.

Comment: Your question is very unclear

Comment: are you trying to run a shell or cmd and from there it execute your code?

Comment: im saying is that if you just put that text and convert it to a exe, whats the result???

Comment: If you make an executable out of this code it will do the same as before.